# Datatable with nested child rows

Tags: datatables

My requirement is to create a table whose parent rows are clickable and having n-level of child. I tried using data table and was successful in displaying the first level of children but failed to display the next level.

```js
 function format(d) {
     // `d` is the original data object for the row
     if (d.child.length) {
         var tableStr = '<table cellspacing="0" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
         for (var i = 0; i < d.child.length; i++) {
             tableStr += '<tr>' +
                 '<td class="details-control"></td>' +
                 '<td>' + d.child[i].name + '</td>' +
                 '<td>' + d.child[i].position + '</td>' +
                 '<td>' + d.child[i].office + '</td>' +
                 '<td>' + d.child[i].salary + '</td>' +
                 '</tr>';
         }
         return tableStr + '</table>';
     }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var table = $('#example').DataTable({
         "ajax": "data/objects.txt",
         "columns": [{
             "className": 'details-control',
             "orderable": false,
             "data": null,
             "defaultContent": ''
         }, 
         { "data": "name" }, 
         { "data": "position" }, 
         { "data": "office" }, 
         { "data": "salary" }],
         "order": [
             [1, 'asc']
         ]
     });

     // Add event listener for opening and closing details
     $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
         var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
         var row = table.row(tr);

         if (row.child.isShown()) {
             // This row is already open - close it
             row.child.hide();
             tr.removeClass('shown');
         } else {
             // Open this row
             row.child(format(row.data())).show();
             tr.addClass('shown');
         }
     });
 });
```

//data content in object.txt

```js
var tableData = {[
{
  "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  "position": "System Architect",
  "salary": "$320,800",
  "start_date": "2011/04/25",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "5421",
  "child": [{
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422",
      "child": [{
          "name": "Cedric Kelly",
          "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
          "salary": "$433,060",
          "start_date": "2012/03/29",
          "office": "Edinburgh",
          "extn": "6224",
            "child": []
      }]
      },{
      "name": "Ashton Cox",
      "position": "Junior Technical Author",
      "salary": "$86,000",
      "start_date": "2009/01/12",
      "office": "San Francisco",
      "extn": "1562",
        "child": []
    }]
}]};
```

Comment: You cannot have `n` level of childs out of the box. If you want you must create dataTables inside dataTables.

Comment: you mean generate datatable on clicking the table row

Comment: Yes! Turn <table> in the child row into a dataTable that have child rows too and so forth.